# How can I make my <h5> fit vertically into a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem and can't seem to find the solution.

I have a header tag nested inside a few divs - here's how it looks:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="layout-left">
    <div class="card-header">
       <h5> I am supposed to be a straight vertical line </h5>
     </div
   </div>
   ... (other divs)
</div>
```

And essentially my problem is that i'm trying to make my h5 tag be vertical, so i did a

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

however it seems to stay at the width that the parent div is at so my letters instead of spacing out they bunch up. I did leave out some content within the divs to cut down on the code, so that's why some divs are flex box's and whatnot.

Here is a [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ej2v3od2/3/) so you can see what I mean.. If the solution must be in Javascript or JQuery library i'm totally fine with it, but if there's a css solution I prefer it.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `width:100%` and add `white-space:nowrap`.

https://jsfiddle.net/c2xm1jog/

```
.card-header h5 {
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: that was a really simple solution.. I spent so long trying to figure it out. But it did indeed work, thank you very much Joe.